# Are these two double await code versions equivalent?

Tags: javascript, async-await, refactoring, es6-promise

If I have these lines:

```
const service = await getService('player');
const players = await service.players();
```

Can I use this one-liner version instead? Are they equivalent?

```
const players = await (await getService('player')).players();
```

Is there an even more streamlined way to write it?

Comment: yes, they are ... and no, not really.

Comment: Equivalent, but your first snippet is easier to understand. I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It's equivalent to in terms of result.

**However,** As @CertainPerformance's comment, you should use the first snippet to be able to `debugger` (as well as to follow best practice) like this.

```js
let getService = (str) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({players: getPlayers}), 1000));
let getPlayers = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("Response data"), 1000));

async function run() { 
  const service = await getService('player');
      console.log(service); // debugger to watch response of each async func
  const players = await service.players();
      console.log(players); // debugger to watch response of each async func
}

run();
```